# PySpark - Input path does not exist on YARN. Works fine locally

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Spark and Python and I am trying to launch a Python script (through a bash run.sh command).
When I run it on local mode, everything is fine. When I try to run it in the cluster(which has spark 2.1.2 without hadoop) then I receive the same error.
I hope this info is enough.

What should I do so that the script runs in yarn?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import sys
import collections
import os
from subprocess import call, Popen
import numpy
import re
import requests
import json
import math

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment

sc = SparkContext("yarn", "test")
record_attribute = sys.argv[1]
in_file = sys.argv[2]


#Read warc file and split in WARC/1.0
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(in_file,
    "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
    conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": "WARC/1.0"})
```

And this is the error

```
7/11/30 14:05:48 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at PythonRDD.scala:553
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/script.py", line 51, in <module>
    ,conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": "WARC/1.0"})
  File "/home/test/spark-2.1.2-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 651, in newAPIHadoopFile
  File "/home/test/spark-2.1.2-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/home/test/spark-2.1.2-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopFile. org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist
```

Comment: Is `in_file` a path that is available to both master and workers? Additionally, what is its value?

Comment: I do not know whether it is available to both masters and workers-how can i see this? The in_file is actually a path for a warc.gz file.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run it on local mode, everything is fine

You are loading a file from the local filesystem, then

When you deploy to the cluster, you need to ensure that `in_file` exists **on all executors** (YARN ResourceManagers), or on some shared filesystem, such as HDFS or S3

You should specify where you data is located in that bash script like `hdfs:///some/input/in_file`

If you did not copy your Hadoop cluster's `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` into a local `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable, or otherwise configure it yourself, then the default behavior is to read a local filesystem, and you will therefore need to use the external filesystem URI  path. For example, HDFS is in the format `hdfs://namenode:port/some/input/in_file`

Note: You need to first upload your file to the remote filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR` properly? This directory should contain client configs of hdfs and yarn service. So that spark application can get resources from Yarn and applications can perform read/write operation to HDFS.

Kindly check the doc given below which gives you info about prerequisites to be followed for spark on yarn.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/running-on-yarn.html

If you deploy spark from cloudera manager or ambari server, All environment variables associated with the client configuration will be deployed by itself.

Answer (score -2):

**Running Python SparkPi in YARN Cluster Mode**

Run the `pi.py` file:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster SPARK_HOME/lib/pi.py 10
```

Please refer to the following link for more information: ["Running Spark Applications on YARN"](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html).

Comment: This doesn't help `input path does not exist`

Comment: i am able open the link: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html

Comment: please try it again @cricket_007

Comment: There's nothing for me to try. I didn't ask the question. Please see the other answer I gave

Comment: @cricket_007 i missed your answer! and that really answers the question!